# How can I set up my server so the teams are always balanced?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

I'm setting up a TF2 server, and I want to set it up so that when a player joins the server, they have to join the side that has less players. This way, the teams will stay fairly even.

What commands can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to enable a feature that anyone who's played the game for 10 minutes should know is on by default.

Comment: @Toomai Unless we got an answer for that already, the question is valid. Even if it would the very first line written when starting a tf2 server. Downvote it if you feel it lacks research but it is not a reason to close it.

Comment: @Toomai, that is not a valid reason to close vote, at all. Itt **is** a valid reason to down vote, but a close vote should never, ever be used as a super downvote.

Comment: Wasn't there agreement somewhere that people shouldn't be asking questions about problems they've never faced?

Comment: @Toomai, why would OP make up a problem just for the point of listing a question? Just because it is an inexistant problem for you, does not mean others would reach the same conclusion. I would have to ask why there would be a command to set auto balance, if auto balance was already automatically in place, regardless.

Comment: @Toonami I would just like to say that it was not on by default for my server, and I did try to research it as well as ask other people and none of my friends seemed to know (over 700 Hrs of tf2 by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several cvars you can use together to do this:

```
mp_forceautoteam 1
mp_autoteambalance 1
mp_teams_unbalance_limit 1
```

Let me describe what each of these does:

- `mp_forceautoteam` automatically assigns players to a team without giving them a team choice. Its behavior is affected by the other two cvars. Default is 0.
- `mp_autoteambalance` makes the game balance the teams. Default is 1.
- `mp_teams_unbalance_limit` tells the server how many more players one team can have than the other.  Anything higher than this number is considered unbalanced.  Default is 1.

There is also `mp_spectators_restricted`, which when set to 1 prevents players from moving to spectator if that would unbalance the teams.